# Create directory at specified path in Python does not work for me

Tags: python-2.7, path, dir

I think I am pretty familiar with how `os.mkdir` and `os.makedirs` work but somehow I'm missing something here. I have a function named `check_for_dir()` in my script `myscript.py` that is located in this path `Users/myuser/Projects/myProject/myscript.py`. I want to create a directory named `mydirectory` in my home folder. It looks like this:

```
import os

path = 'Users/myuser/mydirectory/'

def check_for_dir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

check_for_dir(path)
```

But for some reason the whole structure defined in variable `path` is created in script's location. What this means is that directory `mydirectory/` is created in this path:
`Users/myuser/Projects/myproject/Users/myuser/mydirectory/`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os

path = '/Users/myuser/mydirectory/'

def check_for_dir(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

check_for_dir(path)
```

I think you have to change path as **path = '/Users/myuser/mydirectory/'** Hope this will help

If you specify   path = 'Users/myuser/mydirectory/' then it will be consider as a relative path then creates a folder as you have mentioned in the question

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Could you explain more in detail?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I scanned your answer quickly and didn't notice the absence of backlash. Thanks for that.